# Which is the best tutorial on Oldham's Coupling?

Tags: mechanisms

I am a sophomore in mechanical engineering and am unable to understand the purpose and functioning of Oldham's Coupling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a watch of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utEKKox2WHA It's a marketing video for a specific make/model of oldham coupling, but shows good footage of the coupling running at a variety of RPM's, including failure.

Oldham couplings are used to allow transmission of torque between two parallel shafts, which may be misaligned (non-coaxial) . The allowable misalignment will be shown on the data sheet for each specific coupling.

This may be a static misalignment, or dynamic, such as a driven roller that moves up/down according to the thickness of stock that it is running on top of.

In failure an Oldham Coupling will not transmit any torque, to the output shaft. This contrasts with flexible Jaw Couplings (which can also accommodate some misalignment, although not as much), which, if the insert fails, will continue to transmit torque, albeit with some backlash. Which of these is appropriate depends on which failure mechanism is safer for the system at hand.